# I am fatch data by username from django API using angular4

Tags: django, angular

this is my anglar4 creating app name as **search** i want to fatch data from django rest API. I want that when i give username it give me only this username data.

**app.components.tc**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  username:string = '';

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){}

  onNameKeyUP(event:any){
     this.username = event.target.value;
  }

  getProfile(){
    console.log(this.username)
    this.httpClient.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginAdmin/?username=${this.username}")
    .subscribe(
      (data:any[]) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    )
  }


}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.components.html**
it is my simlple Html which is use to send username from Django API

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="onNameKeyUP($event)">
<button (click)="getProfile()">Get Profile</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {
  filter,
  map,
  switchMap,
  debounceTime,
  distinctUntilChanged,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  profile$: Observable<any>;
  ctrl = new FormControl();

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profile$ = this.ctrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      filter(v => v.length > 2),
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(username =>
        this.httpClient.get(
          `http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginAdmin/?username=${username}`,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<input [formControl]="ctrl">
<div> {{ profile$ | async | json }} </div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: I follow your answer but still not working it fetch  all data but i want only those data which userename type by us.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot comment on the httpClient.get method, because it depends on your backend implementation. My answer should get you started on invoking the httpClient based on the input changes.